# Does image resolution for training/validation affect Yolov3 ability to detecting object from short and long distance

Tags: object-detection, yolo

Let's say I want to be able to detect car models from short and long distance. Does it mean I have to prepare training & validation dataset which contains same car images with multiple resolution?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Setnug

Answer (score 0):

I think your question kind of match with following issue mentioned in [YOLO WIKI](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/wiki/FAQ---frequently-asked-questions#1-i-get-low-accuracy) page:

```
1. I get low accuracy:
    ....
    ....
    4. Your training dataset doesn't suitable for your Test dataset:
          - Training dataset contains: cars (rear view) from distance 100m
          - Test dataset contains: cars (side view) from distance 5m
```

If you look into [How to improve object detection](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-improve-object-detection) section, you can find a **general rule** about how to prepare your training `Dataset` based on your detection target:

> General rule - your training dataset should include such a set of
> relative sizes of objects that you want to detect:

```
train_network_width * train_obj_width / train_image_width ~= detection_network_width * detection_obj_width / detection_image_width

train_network_height * train_obj_height / train_image_height ~= detection_network_height * detection_obj_height / detection_image_height
```

> I.e. for each object from Test dataset there
> must be at least 1 object in the Training dataset with the same
> class_id and about the same relative size:

```
object width in percent from Training dataset ~= object width in percent from Test dataset
```

> That is, if only objects that occupied 80-90% of the image were
> present in the training set, then the trained network will not be able
> to detect objects that occupy 1-10% of the image.

**Your query:**

> **Does it mean I have to prepare training & validation dataset which contains same car images with multiple resolution?**

**Answer:** No, it doesn't necessarily mean that you need to have the same car image of different resolutions.
Rather, you can say that you need to have similar resolution of training images of cars concerning what sizes (in resolution) of cars you want to detect using your trained model.

Comment: Thank you for your lengthy explanations. My next naive question, if my current dataset consists of pics taken 10-15 ft away from the object and in prod I want to be able to detect from 100 ft away, do I have to take another pics from target distance, or can I just zoom out existing pics ?

Answer (score 0):

I think image resolution does not affect YOLO's ability to predict far or near objects. Deep learning models generally make good predictions if the test data is similar to the data it learns and otherwise. The ability is mainly affected by the loss function that presents how you penalize the model for each wrong prediction, you should review YOLO's loss function and refine it a little bit depend on your purpose.